# Ajuda com excesso de processamento

Tags: c#

Estou escrevendo um aplicação em C#. Minha aplicação funciona bem processando até uma certa quantidade de dados. No entanto, se essa quantidade de dados aumenta significativamente, ele entra um estado denominado pelo Visual Studio de "estado de interrupção" e é exibida a seguinte mensagem:

> Assistente para Depuração Gerenciada 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'O CLR não conseguiu fazer a transição do contexto COM 0x9e58a0 para o contexto COM 0x9e57e8 em 60 segundos.`
>
> O thread que possui o context/apartment de destino está provavelmente fazendo uma espera sem bombeamento ou processando uma operação de execução muito longa sem bombeamento das mensagens do Windows. Geralmente, essa situação tem um impacto negativo no desempenho e pode até mesmo levar à falta de resposta do aplicativo ou ao acúmulo contínuo de uso de memória com o tempo`.
>
> Para evitar esse problema, todos os threads com um único apartment em thread (STA) devem usar primitivos de espera de bombeamento (como `CoWaitForMultipleHandles`) e bombear rotineiramente as mensagens durante operações de execução longa.'`

No meu caso, a *thread* está realizando uma operação muito longa "sem bombeamento das mensagens do Windows".

Até então, eu nunca tive que lidar com isso.

Como posso resolver isso? Pode ser um trecho de código (não precisa ser em C#, qualquer pseudo código ajuda).

Comment: Se concorrência é um problema uma possibilidade é a implementação de filas de processamento. Crie um Worker que obtenhas as 'tarefas' de uma fila FIFO.

Comment: Há como exemplificar isso em código? Uma classe?

Comment: Isso pode te dar uma luz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente isso ocorre quando á longos processamentos e o  *debugger* pensa ser um *DeadLock* mas que não necessariamente é!(é só um aviso) Isto somente ocorre em modo de depuração, para desabilitar este aviso basta ir ao menu *Debug* > *windows* > *Exception Settings* procure por *ContextSwitchDeadlock* e desabilite a opção

Comment: Mas, em modo de operação real o programa explode! Acho que a solução tem alguma coisa a ver com a classe destacada CoWaitForMultipleHandles, por isso estou pedindo um trecho de código.

Comment: Não tem como criar um trecho de código aleatório pra exemplificar isto, poderia postar o seu código para analisarmos melhor?

Comment: @Paulo o correto seria você fornecer o código falho não? Afinal o problema ocorre no seu código, devido a mensagem de erro *"O thread que possui o context/apartment de destino está provavelmente fazendo uma espera sem bombeamento"*, isto se refere ao seu código, não adianta muito postar qualquer código aqui, sendo que existem inúmeras maneiras de causar este problema. Edite tua pergunta e poste o código relevante =)

Comment: Meu código não tem problemas. O problema é que eu preciso manter a recepção de recepção de mensagens do windows ativa, enquanto executo o processamento do meu código. Ou seja, é questão de manter duas theards ativas. Mas, eu não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Vocês têm razão. Não era problema de threard que estava fazendo meu programa quebrar. Mas, algo dentro do longo processo. A falta de processamento de mensagens do windows ocasiona a mensagem na interface do programa: "app.exe (não está respondendo)". No meu caso o programa estava quebrando mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

em vez de desabilitar o aviso de código ruim, corrija o código ruim.
basta acrescentar no meio do loop:
Application.DoEvents();
isso vai evitar o deadlock permitindo que outros processos rodem e teu código não vai ficar tão mesquinho querendo tudo só para ele!